# Take page screenshot using Awesomium WebControl and VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, awesomium

I was trying to figure out how to take webpage screenshot from Awesomium WebControl, but i cant find anything usefull. Existing examples are mainly in C and using WebView or they are screenshoting control directly in some way (which is awfull and unreliable solution) or they are using 3rd party service (online 'web screenshoters').

Is there some more simple way how to get screenshot/preview of webpage from Awesomium WebControl? (Idealy without temporary image file)

Comment: Which *`WebControl`*? WPF or WinForms?

Comment: WinForms, Im not sure what exactly WPF is anyway :)